# ASP.NET Core Razor Page anchor tag not working inside an Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a set of razor pages at the usual location for an ASP.NET Core project...

```
/Pages/Index.cshtml
/Pages/About.cshtml
...etc...
```

They use the usual shared layout file for providing the header and footer content for each page...

```
/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
```

Inside the _Layout.cshtml I have anchor tags in the header and footer sections of the page for going back to the index page, like this...

```
<a asp-page="\About">About</a>
```

...which generates an actual href of 'http://localhost/About'. This is correct and works just fine. I have since added more razor pages inside an area, like this...

```
/Areas/Account/Pages/Settings/UserSettings.cshtml
```

I want the same header and footer display for the Account area pages as for my main pages and so I have set the view start file...

```
/Areas/Account/_ViewStart.cshtml
```

...to use the already existing layout, like this...

```
@{
    Layout = "/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

...and sure enough, my UserSettings page now renders the header and footer for the page as expected. With appropriate images and text.

**Except for one problem**. The anchor tags are not generating the correct href for any razor page inside the Account area. Instead of generating...

```
href="http://localhost/About"
```

...it is generating...

```
href="http://localhost/Account/Settings/UserSettings"
```

I believe it is generating a default href for the UserSettings page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you enabled areas for Razor Pages?

Comment: I believe so, I have 'services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);' set inside ConfigureServices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find that you need to change

```
<a asp-page="\About">About</a>
```

to

```
<a asp-page="/About">About</a>
```

`\` is 
Escape character and `/` is the Separator.You won't direct correctly in area if you use `asp-page="\About"`.